# Math Philosophy and Domain

Tags: functions

If I have a discontinuous function, can a union be used to describe its domain? Is the answer I gave correct as well?

> $$\frac{x^2-x-12}{x+3}$$

I can state the domain as $(-\infty,-3)\bigcup(-3,\infty)$.  I am just guessing this since the function is discontinuous at $x=-3$, and the question asks at which intervals is the function continuous.

Comment: The domain of a function is a set, and can be described in whatever way sets can be described.

Comment: Actually you function is not _defined_ at $x=-3$, which is different from being _discontinuous_ at $x=-3$ (which requires first of all to be defined at $x=-3$).

Comment: On the other hand, if the question is *on which intervals is the function continuous*, the answer must of course be a list of intervals, and $(-\infty,-3)\cup(-3,\infty)$ is certainly not an interval, so that cannot be the anwer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Quick Question is the -1 in your comment supposed to be -3?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I thought that the union would represent that the function is not defined at $x=-3$, hence describing the set as $x\in\mathbb{R}; x \ne 3$

Comment: That union describes the set on which the function is defined. But you wrote that the question is «on what intervals is the function continuous?» which is quite different from the question «on what set is the function defined?»

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That makes more sense, because I was just lost.  So being defined does not mean continuity basically, so I basically go with the answer DonAntonio gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to talk about discontinuity in points where the function is not defined in a little moot... but still:

$$\frac{x^2-x-12}{x+3}=\frac{(x+3)(x-4)}{x+3}\stackrel *=x-4$$

where the equality with $\;*\;$ means our function is like the straight line $\;x-4\;$ **but still undefined at** $\;x=-3\;$ , i.e.: it has a hole where $\;x=-3\;$ .